# How can I reconfigure the network to static IP address while /etc/network/interfaces not found?

Tags: networking, network-manager

The book I am following for Malware Analysis is older than the current version of Ubuntu I am using. I am using `Remnux OS`. According to the book, I have to update `/etc/network/interfaces` but in the new version, this file isn't present. I recreated by `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and edited the text but did not work for me to make the static IP of the VM. The content I added into the file is given in the image:

[image: The data in /etc/network/interfaces image.]

After checking other questions I found another path to `/etc/netplan` which contains a Yaml file named `01-netcfg.yaml`. The data in this file is given in the next image. [image: Data in Yaml file]

I want to know now how can I make the static IP address of my VM to `192.168.1.100`?
Hope so I explained all my confusion. If you still need something to answer me, please let me know. I checked many posts but I couldn't understand what steps to do.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 uses netplan for network configuration. The [example section](https://netplan.io/examples/) in the official documentation tells you how to set a static IP.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't support Remnux OS here, only stock Ubuntu flavors.

Comment: @heynnema where is the problem to help here with netplan? I mean this is implemented in stock ubuntu also. If i would use ubuntu and have a clue about netplan I would help immediately

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Pop!_OS, Elementary, Kali, Remnux, etc. all may be BASED on Ubuntu, but other than that, they all customize the OS enough, so that it can not be supported here as Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema the Remnus OS is Ubuntu-based and is its flavour. It's just a specialized version of Ubuntu for Reverse engineering and malware analysts. When I turn it on. the Ubuntu icon and text appears. Thanks.

Comment: @ArturMeinild when I used that example, now the **ifconfig** command doesn't show that **enp0s316f** interface for virtual box IP address. I just changed 10.10.10.0/24 into 192.168.1.100 as a static IP address. I copied whole text from example and pasted so that it doesn't cause any issue but in the result, the interface disappeared in the result of **ifconfig** command.